# Finding a function which is not differentiable at $x_{0}$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives

Let $L \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $f$ be a function that is differentiable on a deleted neighborhood of $x_{0} \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{x \to x_{0}}f'(x)=L$.

Find a function satisfying the above, and such that $f$ is not differentiable at $x_{0}$.

--

So I think that I do not completlely understand, when a function is indeed differentiable at $x_{0}$ and when it's not, and why in both cases I can still find its $f'$?

I will appreciate some explanation about that.

Moreover, I thought of $f(x)=x^x$ or $f(x)=\ln(x^x)$.

If I understand it correctly, than both my $f$'s does not differentiable at $x_{0}=0$, because:

$f'(0)=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^x-0^0}{x-0}$ which is undefined?

or

$f'(0)=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln(x^x)-\ln(0^0)}{x-0}$ which is undefined?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Assuming by "deleted neighborhood" you mean neighborhood with $x_0$ removed, then such a function is necessarily discontinuous at $x_0$, so take a look at easy functions that are discontinuous at a point but differentiable elsewhere

Answer (score 4):

Take $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, with $$f(x)=\begin{cases}Lx~~~\text{ for }x<x_0\\Lx+1~\text{for }x\geq x_0\end{cases}$$

Comment: Isn't $f'(x) = L$ in this case, even for $x_0$?

Comment: @mvw $f$ isn‘t even continuous at $x_0$, so it cannot be differentiable there.

Comment: You are right. I just spotted my error. $h\to 0$ gives $1/h\to\infty$, not $0$.

Comment: Thank you for that!
Are you able to help me in general with my question please?
I do not completely understand, when a function is indeed differentiable at x0 and when it's not, and why in both cases I can still find its $f′$?

Comment: If the function isn't differentiable at a point you can't find $f'$ there (by definition). Saying that the limit $\lim_{x\to x_0} f'(x)$ exists is a different statement (but of course related in some sense). If you want to test whether the function is differentiable or not just use the definition (if possible) or as in this case argue that it is not continuous and hence cannot be differentiable.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate it!
So, is $x^x$ differentiable at $x_{0}=0$? I think it's not because $0^0$ is undefined. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, functions can only be differentiable/continuous inside their domain. So no, $x^x$ is not differentiable at $0$ because it is not defined there.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you have the following theorem.

> Suppose $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and differentiable on $(a,b)\setminus\{c\}$ for some $c\in (a,b)$. If $\lim_{x\to c}f'(x)$ exists, then $f$ is differentiable at $x=c$ and
> $$
> f'(c)=\lim_{x\to c}f'(x).
> $$

(This is a good exercise of the mean value theorem.)

So in order to find your desired example, $f$ must *not* be continuous at $x=c$. This is easy: just move it somewhere else. For example,
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
Lx&x\ne 0\\
1&x=0
\end{cases}.
$$

---

Notes.

If a function $f$ is not defined at $x=x_0$ or it is defined but not continuous at $x_0$, then you can immediate tell that $f$ is not differentiable at $x=x_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Take the function $f(x) = |x-x_0|$.

$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0^-} \frac{|(x_0-h)+x_0|}{-h} = \frac{|h|}{-h}$ and

$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0^+} \frac{|(x_0+h)+x_0|}{h} = \frac{|h|}{h}$.

Comment: First, you need to scale by $L$ so that $f'(x)\to L$. Second, $\lim_{x\to x_0^-}f'(x)=-L$, so approaching from below, the derivative is $-L$.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to x_0} f'(x)$ doesn't exist in your example.